# How to convert array to tuple in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I want to use `IN` operator with tuples:

```sql
WHERE (a, b) IN (('my', 'tuple'))
```

The problem is that I don't have `('my', 'tuple)` as a tuple but array. So I have this:

```sql
WHERE (a, b) IN (['my', 'tuple'])
```

*(the array is passed by my templating engine that is not very flexible. Actually, what I do is `WHERE (a, b) IN (splitByChar('|', 'my|tuple'])`).*

**How can I convert array to tuple? I'm looking for something like `toTuple()`**

```sql
WHERE (a, b) IN (toTuple(['my', 'tuple']))
```

*or more precisely:*

```sql
WHERE (a, b) IN (toTuple(splitByChar('|', 'my|tuple'])))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```sql
SELECT
    ['my', 'tuple'] AS arr,
    arrayMap(x -> (x[1], x[2]), [arr])[1] AS tuple

/*
┌─arr────────────┬─tuple──────────┐
│ ['my','tuple'] │ ('my','tuple') │
└────────────────┴────────────────┘
*/
```

or

```sql
select ['my', 'tuple'] AS arr, tupleConcat(tuple(arr[1]), tuple(arr[2])) AS tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just refer the array elements in the right side of `IN`...

```
WITH splitByChar('|', 'my|tuple') AS arr
SELECT *
FROM VALUES 
( 
  'a String, b String'
, ('my', 'tuple')
, ('my', 'tuples')
) tab
WHERE (a, b) in (arr[1], arr[2])

|a  |b    |
|---|-----|
|my |tuple|
```